# Display message in PHP when the result of mysql query has no value

Tags: php, mysql, return-value

I have a table in PHP which displays the result of the MySQL query.

The database table **item_em** has the **price** details of the items that are available in hypermarkets available in the database table **hypermarket_em**.There are some items that aren't available in the hypermarket. Hence when i display the prices in the table I want those cells with no price as **N/A**.

So my problem is I tried a code myself to display message when database table field has no value.But it doesn't work and I don't get any error as well. Any ideas much appreciated. Thank you.

> Here is my code

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT h_id FROM hypermarket_em") or die(mysql_error());
echo"<tbody><tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ))
{   
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT item_name FROM items_em WHERE h_id=".$row['h_id'])or die(mysql_error());
    while($drop_4 = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
    {
         echo"<th scope=row>".$drop_4['item_name']."</th>";
         $rslt = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM items_em WHERE item_name='".$drop_4['item_name']."' and h_id=".$row['h_id'])or die(mysql_error());
         if (mysql_num_rows($rslt) == 0)
             echo"<td>N/A</td>";
         while($drop = mysql_fetch_array( $rslt ))
         {
             echo"<td>".$drop['price']."</td>";
         }
    }
}
echo"</tr></tbody>";
```

Comment: Try to get size of the $res, like this: `size($res)`, if zero, means no result.

Comment: i get error saying "size" is undefined..:(

Comment: Can you explain what the X and Y axis are? What column do they correspond to?

Comment: X=h_name from hypermarket_em ,Y=item_name from items_em,cells are the price in items_em

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my answer.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT h_id FROM hypermarket_em") or die(mysql_error());
echo"<tbody><tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ))
{   
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT item_name FROM items_em WHERE h_id=".$row['h_id'])or die(mysql_error());
    while($drop_4 = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
    {
            echo"<th scope=row>".$drop_4['item_name']."</th>";
            $rslt = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM items_em WHERE item_name='".$drop_4['item_name']."' and h_id=".$row['h_id'])or die(mysql_error());
        while($drop = mysql_fetch_array( $rslt ))
        {
            echo"<td>".$drop['price']."</td>";
        }
    }
}
$res = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT h_id FROM hypermarket_em") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ))
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT item_name FROM items_em WHERE h_id=".$row['h_id'])or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)<=0)
        echo"<td>N/A</td>";
}
echo"</tr></tbody>";
```

I had to execute the same query twice as i want the item names and the price values in the order. So I first print the item names and then only the prices or "N/A" message.

Thank you all for your help..:)

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing your `mysql_num_rows` and check if you have `>` than `0` rows-

```
if (mysql_num_rows($rslt) > 0){
    while($drop = mysql_fetch_array( $rslt )){
      echo"<td>".$drop['price']."</td>";}
}
else{
     echo"<td>N/A</td>";}
```

---

Edit-

I think what you are wanting to do then is something like this-

```
while($drop = mysql_fetch_array( $rslt )){
    if ($drop['price'] == ''){
      echo"<td>N/A</td>";}
    else{
      echo"<td>".$drop['price']."</td>";}
```

Comment: as many times as the price for the item for a particular hypermarket is not available

Comment: I have tried this code already. But the line "if ($drop['price'] == '')" doesn't seem to work, that's why i used mysql_num_rows..

Comment: what do you get when you `echo mysql_num_rows($rslt)`? Is it 6, what your screenshot shows?

Comment: Hey thanks. Now i get it. I have to write the code in my previous while loop.

Comment: Yeah your `SELECT` is only getting the row where `h_id=".$row['h_id']`, so you won't get additional rows until you loop again at the top with `while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ))`

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array( $res );
if (!empty($data)) {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ))
   {   
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT item_name FROM items_em WHERE h_id=".$row['h_id'])or die(mysql_error());
      while($drop_4 = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
      {
         echo"<th scope=row>".$drop_4['item_name']."</th>";
         $rslt = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM items_em WHERE item_name='".$drop_4['item_name']."' and h_id=".$row['h_id'])or die(mysql_error());
         if (mysql_num_rows($rslt) == 0)
             echo"<td>N/A</td>";
         while($drop = mysql_fetch_array( $rslt ))
         {
             echo"<td>".$drop['price']."</td>";
         }
      }
   }
} else {
   echo "<td>No record found</td>";
}
```

Comment: this did work. but the message is being displayed in wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to do here, but it seems like you might want to simplify your query as well.  Try something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    hypermarket_em h
    LEFT JOIN items_em i ON ( h.h_id = i.h_id );
```

Using this query, you can do something like:

```
while($drop = mysql_fetch_array( $rslt )){
    echo"<td>" . ( empty( $drop['price'] ) ? 'N/A' : $drop['price'] ) . "</td>";
}
```